# Creating shortucts in SSMS 2008 R2

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ssms, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to create a shortcut to change the connection of a query in SSMS. Is there a way to manually assign shortcut keys to buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in Tools - Options - Keyboard.

See also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174178.aspx).

Comment: Awesome! The second link is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS Tools Pack Snippets is the nearest I can find to highly customisable keyboard shortcuts/hotkeys. For SQL 2012 on it's no longer free. The options mentioned above (unless I'm missing something obvious) don't seem to allow you to set your own shortcuts. There are twelve keyboard shortcuts listed  (from Alt+F1 to Ctrl+0) but for the life of me I can't work out how you can add your own to this list.